# Definition of sign

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

The following definition is in my notes with no explanation:

> $$\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }\sigma(p)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\\-1,&\text{if }\sigma(p)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=-p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\end{cases}$$

I'm a little confused by what it actually means in practice and what sigma represents. Any explanation or clarification would be great.

Comment: Doesn't it even say what $\sigma$ and $p$ are? Are the notes available online so that we could see them?

Comment: It *might* be that $p$ is a multivariate polynomial and $\sigma$ is an element of a group acting on the ring of polynomials. However, how would one warrant that $\sigma(p)$ equals one of $p$ and $-p$? Some **context** would be great

Comment: No, but from previous notes I believe p represents a polynomial and sigma represents a permutation. I'm afraid the notes are not online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *permutation* $\sigma$ on a set $X = \{1,\dotsc,n\}$ is a bijection of the set $X$ on itself. Meaning that $\sigma$ maps any element of $X$ to another unique element of $X$ (maybe the same). For example, a permutation could look like this:

$$ \sigma=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

Meaning that $\sigma(1)=2$, $\sigma(2)=5$, $\sigma(3)=4$ and so on. Permutations have applications in various fields. In linear algebra, they are extremely useful for defining the determinant as you can see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A0n_matrices). The determinant is an example where you also need the sign of the permutation.

For $\sigma \in S_n$ (Permutation Group of the numbers $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$), let $P(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = \prod_{i<n}(x_i-x_j)$, then we can define

$$\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = \frac{P(x_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc,x_{\sigma(n)})}{P(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)}$$

Since the polynomial $P(x_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc,x_{\sigma(n)})$ has the same factors as the polynoial $P(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$ we have that either $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = 1$ or $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = -1$.

This is equivalent to

$$ P(x_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc,x_{\sigma(n)}) = \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)P(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$$

If you let $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = 1$ or $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = -1$ respectively, you get you definition.

Also possible and more common is the definitions of the sign as $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = (-1)^n$ where $n$ is the number of transposition in the decomposition of $\sigma$. A *transposition* is a permutation where you only swap two elements and leave the rest untouched. So the decomposition is the product of transpositions $\tau_1,\cdots,\tau_n$ such that $\tau_1 \circ \cdots \circ \tau_n = \sigma$.
This is well-defined as it can be proven that even though the decomposition of a permutation is not unique, the number of transpositions always stays the same.

Moreover, this is equivalent to $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) = (-1)^n$ where $n$ is the number of *inversions* of $\sigma$. An inversion is a pair $i,j \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$ such that $i < j$ but $\sigma(i) > \sigma(j)$. If we look at the permutation above, we have for example the inversion $1 < 5$ but $2 = \sigma(1) > \sigma(5) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, cleared things up a lot! The only thing I am struggling with is a statement such as $\sigma(i; j) = \tau$

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't seen this notation yet. Could you describe a little more the context? Often, $\tau$ refers to permutations - so this could mean that you apply $\sigma$ to the tupel $(i, j)$ and then interpret the result as a transposition (where you swap $\sigma(i)$ and $\sigma(j)$). But that's only a guess without knowing the context.

Comment: for example, in the following question: http://i.imgur.com/mrxSxSa.png

Comment: In this case $\sigma(i,j)=\tau$, we have that $(i,j)$ is a transposition and $\sigma (i,j)$ is the composition of both (first apply $(i,j)$ then $\sigma$). 

Remark: As you can see, notation  varies as I personally use $(i,j)$ for tuples and $(i~~j)$ for transpositions. Therefore, context is always important.

Answer (score 0):

The sign or **signum function** is defined as
$$\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}
-1&\text{if}\ x\lt 0,\\
0&\text{if}\ x=0,\\
1&\text{if}\ x\gt 0.\\
\end{cases}$$
It simply returns the sign of $x$ in the form of $-1$ or $1$. If $x$ is $0$, then $0$ is returned.
Here are some examples, 
$$ \operatorname{sgn}(-5)=-1 $$
$$ \operatorname{sgn}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=1 $$
$$ \operatorname{sgn}(6-6)=0 $$

Since no **context** was provided for the functions $\sigma$ and $p$, I cannot provide a meaningful interpretation.

My best **guess** is that the $\sigma(p)$ function changes the sign of $p$ and outputs the modified $p$. In which $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma(p))$ outputs $-1$ or $1$, assuming that $p$ and $\sigma(p)$ is not zero.